# How do I change a the name property in package.json?

Tags: json, node.js

My `package.json` file looks like so:

```
{
  "name": "Orignal Name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "An App",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.3.x"
  },
  "author": "An author",
  "license": "BSD-2-Clause",
  "dependencies": {
    "jade": "~0.35.0",
    "express": "~3.4.4",
    "stylus": "~0.40.2",
    "mongoose": "~3.8.0",
    "passport-local": "~0.1.6",
    "passport": "~0.1.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "karma-mocha": "~0.1.0",
    "mocha": "~1.14.0",
    "karma-chai-plugins": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.3",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.9",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma": "~0.10.5"
  }
}
```

How do I change the `"name":` attribute `"Original Name"` to `"New Name"` without breaking `npm install` ?

I tried simply updating the name and attempting `npm install` but npm install won't read the `package.json` file now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From [npm doc](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html), you can t have url unsafe character, take the name of any already existing package, nor have dots or slash. Are thoses condition respected for the new name?

Comment: Yes those conditions are satisfied. Both names have the same format of characters only without spaces and both are unique to any name on the system.

Comment: And unique to all npm?

Comment: Yes, Unique to npm and all dependencies.

Comment: Did you change the version too?

Comment: I am thinking that NPM takes the initial implementation of package.json and creates some other tasks using the name provided in the package.json file, and now the "New Name" is not matching the the "Original Names" elsewhere.

Comment: No version has remained the same, and changing the name back corrects the issue.

Comment: `npm install` isn't working within this directory or is this in node_modules and an `npm install` from a dependent isn't working? Guessing the folder name needs to match the new name as well.

Comment: I solved the issue by creating a fresh package.json file, reinstalling all dependencies, and migrating the code. It wasn't so much of a pain as it was inconvenient. Thanks to all for your input.

Answer (score 10):

just edit the name in package.json.
The name must following the rules https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#name

Comment: Does this break anything with databases or deployment or iOS or Android deployment

Comment: how gets the name in the package-lock.json updated??

Comment:   You got 10 points! 

Answer (score 2):

Just change the name in `package.json` file. Changes to the package should come along with changes to the version.

Once you change the name in `package.json`, the name and/or version properties in `package-lock.json` should also be changed. This can be done by simply running `npm install`

From [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json)

> Some rules:
>
> - The name must be less than or equal to 214 characters. This includes    the scope for scoped packages.
> - The names of scoped packages can begin    with a dot or an    underscore. This is not permitted without a scope.
> - New packages must not have uppercase letters in the name.
> - The name ends up being part of a URL, an argument on the command    line, and a folder name. Therefore, the name can't contain any non-URL-safe characters.