# Changing the name of package.json in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, rename, package.json

I would like to rename my *node.js* project. [According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039633/how-do-i-change-a-package-json-name#44189101), all I had to do is change the value of the `name` property in *package.json*.

That said, the new version now includes *package-lock.json*. So is changing the name in *package-lock.json*, in addition to changing it in *package.json*,  sufficient? Do I have to change the name in another file?

Is there an **npm** command that I can run that applies the name change correctly and automatically updates it with all the naming rules verified?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you change the name in `package.json`, it must also be changed in `package-lock.json`. You can run `npm install` to update `package-lock.json` after changing the `name` attribute in `package.json`.